# D3 - Stacked bar chart, position bars

Tags: angular, d3.js

I have a stackbiltz here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/d3-stacked-trend-bar-v5eyxx?file=src/app/bar-chart.ts

I'm creating a stacked bar chart in Angular using D3.

The x axis is months and each month has two stacked bar charts.

I didnt know how to the position the bars on the x axis using D3's functions so I positioned them by dividing the number of bars by the width.

```
.attr('width', (this.width/this.data.length)-2)

.attr('x', (d:any, i:any)=>{
    return (i * this.width/this.data.length);
})
```

This sort of works but the month tick should be inbetween each bar of the month but this is off.

How can I position the bars correctly using D3's built in functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to split up the bandwidth in the 2 bars for each month

```
.attr('width', this.x.bandwidth()*0.95*0.5 )
.attr('x', (d:any, i:any)=>{
    return (this.x(d.data.date) + (i%2) * 0.525 * this.x.bandwidth());
})
```

Comment: Would you kindly look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68405542/stacked-bar-plot-chart-in-angular-using-d3-js) question please, see if you can help me?

Comment: @CatarinaRuna Look at the stackblitz in the OP question

Comment: I cannot understand how that would resolve my issue :-(

Answer (score 0):

As you're using `d3.scaleBand()` for the x scale, you can use [band_bandwidth](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale#band_bandwidth) to set the widths of the bars.

**Relevant changes:**

1. Bandwidth to the bars:

   ```
   .attr('width', this.x.bandwidth())
   ```
2. `x` positioning of the bars based on date.

   ```
   .attr('x', (d:any, i:any)=>{
       return this.x(d.data.date);
   })
   ```

A fork considering the above changes:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/d3-stacked-trend-bar-dqezuw?file=src/app/bar-chart.ts

Hope this helps.

Comment: Lol my bad. I didn't read the question correctly! I just went with a **scaleBand-bar-chart-center-ticks** instinct. Anyway, glad it's resolved!