# stacked bar plot/chart in angular using D3.js

Tags: html, angular, typescript, d3.js

I have put some dummy data into a `csv` file in my Angular project:

```
group,Nitrogen,normal,stress
banana,12,1,13
poacee,6,6,33
sorgho,11,28,12
triticum,19,6,1
```

I created a `stacked-bar` component and put the following in its `html` script:

```
<figure id="stacked-bar"></figure>
```

I then wrote this typescript file to display a stacked bar:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as d3 from 'd3';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-stacked-bar',
  templateUrl: './stacked-bar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./stacked-bar.component.css']
})
export class StackedBarComponent implements OnInit {

  svg: any;

  margin = 50;
  width = 750 - (this.margin * 2);
  height = 400 - (this.margin * 2);

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.createSvg();
    d3.csv("/assets/fruits.csv").then(data => this.drawBars(data));
  }

  createSvg(): void {
    this.svg = d3.select("figure#stacked-bar")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", this.width + (this.margin * 3))
    .attr("height", this.height + (this.margin * 3))
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + this.margin + "," + this.margin + ")");
  }

  drawBars(data): void {
    const subgroups = data.columns.slice(1)
    const groups = data.map(d => (d.group))

    // Create the X-axis band scale.
    const x = d3.scaleBand()
    .range([0, this.width])
    .domain(data.map(d => d.groups))
    .padding(0.2);

    // Draw the X-axis on the DOM.
    this.svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + this.height + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x).tickSizeOuter(0))
    
    // Create the Y-axis band scale.
    const y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([5.75, 9])
    .range([this.height, 0]);

    // Draw the Y-axis on the DOM.
    this.svg.append("g")
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

    // color palette - one color per subgroup
    const color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
    .domain(subgroups)
    .range(['#e41a1c','#377eb8','#4daf4a'])

    // stack the data per subgroup
    const stackedData = d3.stack()
    .keys(subgroups)
    (data)

    // Create and fill the bars.
    this.svg.append("g")
    .selectAll("g")
    .data(stackedData)
    .join("g")
    .attr("fill", d => color(d.key))
    .selectAll("rect")    
    .data(data)
    .join("rect")
    .attr("x", d => x(d.data.group))
    .attr("y", d => y(d[1]))
    .attr("height", d => y(d[0]) - y(d[1]))
    .attr("width",x.bandwidth())
  }
}
```

But all I get is the following empty plot:

[image]

**What am I doing wrong? Could someone please help me find my mistake?**

Thanks

Comment: why do you bind `data` when you create `rect`s, look what `stackedData` is and how to create rects from this. Use a lot of `console.log` to see what is known at which arrow fuunction, even `data()` can have an arrow function

Comment: I got the idea from a tutorial, but the same program dos not work in my Angular project...

Comment: then place `console.log` to follow the logic in the script/call backs, are there any `rects`, use the Dev Tools of the browser, to make it easier for us set up a Stackblitz of your code